# Oracle & WebSecurity - Should I use two different databases?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, security, webmatrix, membership-provider

Our clients are running an Oracle 10g server from their old system.
The new system should use the same DB and enhance functionality.

After a long research online I realized that in order to get `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity` working for us, we need to create a custom membership, inheriting from `ExtendedMembershipProvider`.
I tried using Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, but their libraries don't implement `ExtendedMembershipProvider`, so they lack functionality, and furthermore cannot be used with the `WebSecurity` class which offers great features.

Implementing `ExtendedMembershipProvider` manually is like reinventing the wheel.
My thought was to install the free SQL Server Express edition on the client's server, and use a small database just for the users and sessions.
Other stuff will be kept on the Oracle server.

I would love any opinion or insight on the matter.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I certainly understand the frustration with Oracle products, and I share your reaction that working with it is costly and difficult. You may not have any choice, though. This is something where your client might have some say-so that you're going to be forced into complying with. They maintain the environment, so their standards go. In addition to their standards about where you can and can't install software, they may have standards about how they want their data stored. If they shoot down your idea, another option that might be more palatable to them is using SQLite.

Comment: You might also want to reconsider using Membership Provider at all, or maybe only using a subset that doesn't require `ExtendedMembershipProvider`.

Comment: All that said, I don't think this question is a good fit for StackOverflow. It would likely have opinion based answers, and the "best" answer really depends on a lot of factors that we don't have all the details on. The only general advice I can offer is to weigh the costs and benefits. You've rightly identified that the current course is going to be costly and raised the question of whether it's worth it. The problem is that whether it's worth it depends on things like who's going to use it and how much reuse it will get. It's always an educated guess based on what info you have available.

Comment: Oh, and also make sure you make your superior or team lead aware of your concerns. They should help you identify risks and problems with the approach you're considering, and help you flush out your ideas. Such discussion might even inspire new ideas.

Comment: Wise words jpmc26.
Very much appreciated.
Seems like I've found a work around the issue.
I'm currently writing my own class, inheriting `ExtendedMembershipProvider`, and wrapping `OracleMembershipProvider`.
This makes implementation of the abstract base class a lot easier, because many functions simply end up in a call to the oracle provider.

The missing peaces that the oracle provider don't supply, I completed with .NET tools, and a little bit of my own code.
Currently I'm having an issue with the

Comment: Currently I'm having an issue with the connection to the database, which seem to work when I don't wrap the oracle provider BTW.

When I figure everything out I'll post an article, cause this sure was a long ride, and not a pleasant one.
Strangely enough I couldn't find a lot of material online regarding this issue.